# How to open links in Lightning-Experience Setup in other browser-tabs and browser-windows and imporve history+deeplinks

Tags: lightning-experience, administration, navigation, setup

In Aloha UI and other web-apps I typically make massive use of many browser-tabs and multiple browser windows side-by-side on large screens.

I open them by right-click on the link, then "open in new tab" or "open in new window" (typical browser feature in context menus for any anchor-tags). Or even faster, I hammer the middle button and have stuff loaded in background as tabs, especially when the content loads slowly...

After switching to Lightning Experience, I found at least in the new Setup, this habit is mostly not good anymore. The reason is, that on most a-tags the href-attribute is now href="javascript:void(0)" and the loading happens by event-handlers. I think the reason is a SPA-pattern in mind, where the Setup-tree stays put an only the content will be replaced by ajax.

Now it would have been nice, that the href-attrs had been populated with the URLs in addition to the event-handling for SPA-page-loads, e.g.

- Users > Users : it could be href=`https://eu5.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#/setup/page?nodeId=ManageUsers&address=%2F005%3FisUserEntityOverride%3D1%26retURL%3D%252Fsetup%252Fhome&t=1445014622085`
- Users > Profiles : it could be href=`https://eu5.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#/setup/page?nodeId=Profiles&address=%2Fsetup%2Fui%2Fprofilelist.jsp%3Fsetupid%3DProfiles%26retURL%3D%252Fsetup%252Fhome&t=1445014669372`

Since all the difference is after the #, it should work fine also for SPA-usecases and might have been resulted in the best of both worlds... but currently, we get only the event-mechanism and rather useless hrefs, stripping some standard browser features.

For me that feels very uncomfortable. Is there a way to improve the navigation somehow by configuration or workarounds? If not, are there plans to improve this by Salesforce or should we better get used to live with lots of href="javascript:void(0)" in the UI...?

An other thing is, that the title-tag does not update on navigation. It sticks at just "Lightning Experience", where it was "All Users ~ Salesforce" and "User Profiles ~ Salesforce" in Aloha for the above example. Side-effect of this situation is, that the navigation-history and deep-links get a very poor feeling since all pages (or partials) are indistinctively labeled just "Lightning Experience" in the history and at deep-links. (Also a SPA-sideeffect IMO. Probably a simple update of the title-tag on navigation could make it perfect)

Any feedback, suggestions or workarounds are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Current Workaround:**
Copy the current page url (`CMD+L` + `CMD+C`), open a new tab (`CMD+T`), paste (`CMD+V`), reload (`Enter`), then click your link. That's the closest I could get to my usual `CMD-Click` workflow with Salesforce windows.

**Long-Term Fix:** Vote up the idea.

[Lightning UI needs to support CTRL/COMMAND + CLICK (open link in new tab)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000CIt7AAG)

Answer (score 0):

URL in Lightning Experience doesn't work that great. But, I do have a workaround for the question you have posted and it would work exactly what you need

1. Create a Visualforce Page
2. Make sure to checkbox on "*Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages.*"
3. On the VF page use Hyperlink reference:
   `href= "https://www.urlname.com">URLNANME`

For example:

```
<p><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></p></dd>
```

Make sure to add the Visualforce Page, Standard Lightning Component on your home or record detail page. Now, open the link on your vf page and it should open in a new tab.

In order to have the Lightning Experience Look and feel try using Salesforce Lightning Design System (you can download the SLDS package from here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/)